# KUbuntu, Python and libtcod - console_is_window_closed not working...?

Tags: python, python-2.7, strace, ubuntu, libtcod

I've done a reasonable amount of coding with the libtcod library, both the C# and python wrappers. My current setup is KUbuntu 14.10, python 2.7.8, and libtcod 1.5.2.

I've made a few programs that work fine, but the latest I've just started doesn't seem to want to allow me to close the console window.

I can send a `CTRL+C` from the console that I run the program from, and it will close, but, no amount of clicking on the window's "x" button, or `Alt+F4`s seem to work.

My code is as follows:

```
'''
justclose.py
'''

import sys
import time
import libtcodpy as libtcod

libtcod.console_set_custom_font(b'lucida12x12_gs_tc.png', libtcod.FONT_TYPE_GREYSCALE | libtcod.FONT_LAYOUT_TCOD)
libtcod.console_init_root(50,50, "The ever-present window", False)
libtcod.console_flush()

while not libtcod.console_is_window_closed():
  time.sleep(1)

sys.exit
```

When I run the program, the console comes up, as expected, and sits around waiting for console_is_window_closed to return true, which it never does. I'm not sure where the problem lies. I can run other programs that use the same initialisation code, and same `while` loop and which respond just fine to me clicking the close button on the console window.

I've tried looking through an strace of the process, but, I'm not sure I'm up to the task of deciphering it. Nothing looked immediately out of the ordinary.

I'd like some advice on how to track down what's going wrong. Thanks.

EDIT: specifically, I'd like to know how I can check that the close window event is propagating at all, and if so, how far, where it's getting trapped/ignored, that sort of thing. When I run through strace, I see absolutely nothing happening when I click the close button. Is there some better way to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `time.sleep(1)` with `libtcod.console_check_for_keypress()`. When the program sleeps 1 millisecond for each iteration, the program can not respond when you press X. It exits when you press `CTRL+C` because the program receives the SIGINT signal and it exits immediately. Replacing `time.sleep(1)` with `libtcod.console_check_for_keypress()` makes the program check the key pressed on the keyboard, if there is one. That way, the program doesn't block the execution.